# SQLITE ORDER BY Month and Week data From "MM/dd/yyyy" format

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with a column named sell_date in the date format.

In this column I have the following date in this format "MM/dd/yyyy".

What I want is to select the rows ordered by the week and month wise. Like if i select Jan month and an year from spinner it will show all the rows of that month-year format.
And For weekly i have no idea how to do it :(

Is there such SQLite function that does that??

I already tried strftime('%m', sell_date ) but ditn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
ORDER BY (substr(sell_date,7,4)||substr(sell_date,1,2)||substr(sell_date,4,2));
```

This would require strict adherence to MM/dd/yyyy that is 01,02..... for both the day and the month parts (e.g. 1/1/2018 wouldn't work as expected).

However, it is far better to store dates in one of the recognised formats which can just be sorted and additionally allows the dates to be managed via inbuilt date and time functions such as **strftime** *(and it's because the date isn't in a reconised format that `strftime('%m', sell_date )` didn't work for you)*.

You could have used `strftime('%m',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2))` instead of `strftime('%m', sell_date )` (again only if there were strict adherence to MM/dd/yyyy)

With regard to weekly, you can use the %W to get the week in the year, if that's what you mean by weekly. Again if the date is in a recognised format, so `strftime('%W',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2))` would return the week in the year.

Applying both, you could use :-

```
ORDER BY 
    (substr(sell_date,7,4)||substr(sell_date,1,2)||substr(sell_date,4,2)),
    strftime('%W',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2))
```

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

### Example

Consider the following which produces two results. The first Selecting all rows (3 are inserted with dates 10/14/2018 (week 41), 09/12/2018 (week 37) and 11/13/2018 (week 46) order as expected (by month and then by week).

For illustration columns are generated that show the month and the week of the year. The week column is also used in the second query to select rows that match a week (week 37 aka 09/12/2018) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (sell_date TEXT);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('10/14/2018'),('09/12/2018'),('11/13/2018');

SELECT *, 
    strftime('%m',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2)) AS month,
    strftime('%W',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2)) AS week
FROM table1 
ORDER BY 
    (substr(sell_date,7,4)||substr(sell_date,1,2)||substr(sell_date,4,2)),
    strftime('%W',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2))
;

SELECT *, 
    strftime('%m',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2)) AS month,
    strftime('%W',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2)) AS week
FROM table1 
WHERE CAST(week AS INTEGER) = 37
ORDER BY 
    (substr(sell_date,7,4)||substr(sell_date,1,2)||substr(sell_date,4,2)),
    strftime('%W',substr(sell_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(sell_date,1,2)||'-'||substr(sell_date,4,2))
```

The first query results in :-

[image]

The second, with the WHERE clause (casting the value to an INTEGER) that selects rows according to a specific week in the year, results in :-

[image]

Now if the dates were stored in a recognised format (YYYY-MM-DD) then the above would be the simpler :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (sell_date TEXT);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('2018-10-14'),('2018-09-12'),('2018-11-13');

SELECT *, strftime('%m',sell_date), strftime('%W',sell_date)
FROM table2 
ORDER BY sell_date, strftime('%W',sell_date)
;

SELECT *, strftime('%m',sell_date), strftime('%W',sell_date)
FROM table2 
WHERE CAST(strftime('%W',sell_date) AS INTEGER) = 37
ORDER BY sell_date, strftime('%W',sell_date)**strong text**
```

Comment: substr(sell_date,7,4)||substr(sell_date,1,2)||substr(sell_date,4,2)
what does it means?

Comment: and how to match data with given data?

Comment: You apply the above to the WHERE clause in the same way.

Comment: It means take 4 characters starting from the 7th character (the year part) concatenate this with the characters starting from the 1st characater (the month part) and also concatenate it with 2 characters starting from the 4th character(the day of the month part) thus 01/03/2018 becomes 20180103 (in the second it adds a hyphen between the parts so you get 2018-03-01, this being a recognised format and thus usable by **strftime**).